# How to define a click area on a button with react native?

Tags: react-native

I'm currently developing an app using react native and I'm using react-navigation to navigate between screens, using buttons in my header (back arrow for example).

It's working well, however even if my icon is the right size it seems like the click area is really narrow and I struggle with it.

Do you know how I could define a click zone on my button for it to be clicked easier? I've tried the `hitslop` prop but it's not working for me (maybe it's been deprecated?).

Here is my button:

```
var backArrow =
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}>
    <Ionicons name="ios-arrow-back" size={22} color="#ff8c00" />
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

I'm using Expo and testing on an iPhone 6s Plus.

Comment: try wrapping the icon with a view, and make the whole view clickable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrapping the `Ionicons` in a `TouchableOpacity` will only provide a clickable area as large as the `Ionicons` component. You can increase the size of the clickable area with the following structure:

```
<TouchableOpacity>
  <View>
    <Ionicons />
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

by styling the `View` to be as large as you require it.

Comment: TouchableOpacity already has a native backing view, so you can apply `padding` to it and avoid the additional view in between.

Comment: The `View` wrapping solution is pretty nice, however it requires some styling afterwards (dealing with absolute position because I decided to let my status bar show) but it's definitely not ideal when it comes to testing on other devices... The `padding` prop for `TouchableOpacity` doesn't require more styling so there's that, thanks!

Comment: @Flora `react-navigation` exposes a `HEIGHT` static property on their `Header`. You can use this to determine what height to give your `View`. That is, `import { Header } from "react-navigation"; ... console.log("You could try setting the height on your View to ", Header.HEIGHT);`

Comment: @Charles yeah right, I actually tried to rely on that but the `padding` prop makes it easier for my needs. Thanks anyway:)